# Move from Activity class to AppCompatActivity class

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to develop an Android Application that will play through a video and then transition to another activity.

The issue I'm having is that the video needs to be played FullScreen and in order to do so I had to switch the extends from "AppCompatActivity" to "Activity" otherwise the program would crash when trying to run full screen.

So when I transition to the next activity I had to call that class with extends Activity as well.
Now when I try to implement a drawer sidebar I'm running into issues because the class doesn't extend AppCompat, and is having explicit issues with "getSupportActionBar"

(The video plays, and transitions to the second screen without issue it's just proceeding from there that I'm caught on)

Is there any way to have my second activity extend AppCompat, without it crashing? Or if anyone is aware of a more effective way of implementing this?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

    VideoView splash = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.SplashView);

    Uri splashPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.phsplash);


    splash.setVideoURI(splashPath);
    splash.start();

    final int interval = 7000;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            Intent goHome = new Intent(Main.this, HomeView.class);
            startActivity(goHome);

        }
    };

    handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);

}
}
```

xml

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/SplashView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**There is then the Home view (Not finished writing due to AppCompat issue)**

```
public class HomeView extends Activity {

private ListView theDrawer;
private ArrayAdapter<String> theAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    theDrawer = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawlayout);

    theOptions();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
private void theOptions(){
    String[] panelarray = {"About PHam", "Upcoming Projects", "Idea Submit", "Locate PHam"};
    theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, panelarray);
    theDrawer.setAdapter(theAdapter);

    theDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(HomeView.this, "WTF is Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
private void setupDrawer(){

}
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="This is the Home Screen!"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navlist"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And then Finally the manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.phsplash.captain.pcketham">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/phico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeView"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Log Cat Error Files when implementing Public class HomeView extends AppCompatActivity:

```
11-15 21:05:54.857 13627-13627/? E/Typeface: SANS_LOC file not found.
11-15 21:05:54.867 13627-13627/? E/Typeface: SANS_LOC file not found.
11-15 21:06:02.107 13627-13627/com.phsplash.captain.pcketham E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1
                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:425)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:518)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:708)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:348)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                                       at com.phsplash.captain.pcketham.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:22)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-15 21:06:02.117 13627-13627/com.phsplash.captain.pcketham E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.phsplash.captain.pcketham, PID: 13627
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phsplash.captain.pcketham/com.phsplash.captain.pcketham.HomeView}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                   at com.phsplash.captain.pcketham.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:23)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Updated LogCat with `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`:

```
11-15 21:37:15.627 27184-27184/? E/Typeface: SANS_LOC file not found.
11-15 21:37:15.627 27184-27184/? E/Typeface: SANS_LOC file not found.
11-15 21:37:22.867 27184-27184/com.phsplash.captain.pcketham E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1
                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:425)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:518)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
                                                                                       at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:708)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:348)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                                       at com.phsplash.captain.pcketham.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:22)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-15 21:37:22.877 27184-27184/com.phsplash.captain.pcketham E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.phsplash.captain.pcketham, PID: 27184
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phsplash.captain.pcketham/com.phsplash.captain.pcketham.HomeView}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                   at com.phsplash.captain.pcketham.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:23)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Have you add appCompat library to your project? Then extend your Activity with `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve **appCompat** error, you need to add support library to your app build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

Remember to always adjust your `androidBuildToolsVersion`, `androidCompileSdkVersion`, and `androidTargetSdkVersion` with the same API version. In this case, you need to use API Level 24.

Then you can extend your `Activity` with `AppCompatActivity`, something like:

```
public class HomeView extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...
}
```

Read more for **Support Library** from:

1. [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)
2. [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

**UPDATE**

Based on your error log, it means that you need to use AppCompat as the theme for you activity. Change styles.xml resource with AppCompat, something like this:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>   <!-- Your primary color -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>    <!-- Your dark color -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>    <!-- your accent color -->
  </style>
```

Then add the theme to your Activity or Application in **AndroidManifest.xml** with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` something like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/phico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: my dependencies currently have:
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
}

it still crashes once the video fails

Comment: Please add the stacktrace/error log to your question.

Comment: Please see the logcat error files placed in the original question

Comment: That means, you need to change the style to AppCompat

Comment: Added updated LogCat, updated styles as indicated, app still crashing when loading the startactivity for HomeView

Comment: Have you applied it to your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?. like this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: First try to add to your `<application .. `

Comment: You sir, are a magician. Thank you for your support it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: AppCompat v7 is the only library needed, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007, I read from [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)  on `v7 Support Libraries` section that says **Note: This library depends on the v4 Support Library.**, so we need to add v4 Support library. I'll stand corrected.

Comment: It's a transitive dependency. By compiling v7, you get v4. Same with the design library, that includes v7 and recyclerview on its own. You can run the gradle dependencies task to see the dependency tree

Answer (score 3):

Extend your second class from **AppCompatActivity** instead of **Activity**.

```
public class HomeView extends AppCompatActivity
```

Happy coding. Cheers!

**EDIT**
For that greatness who just downvoted my answer, here is a snippet of the code without any error from Android Studio:

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity{
  private ListView theDrawer;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> theAdapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

and here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()) to necessary documentation about support action bar.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, although that does not work.
the code deploys and the video runs, but as soon as the startactivity launches the app "Unfortunately, has stopped"